Magento 2 - layered navigation filter missing (when attribute value is not set on at least 1 product)?
I have noticed that if attribute value is not set on at least 1 product then filter for that attribute wont be shown in magento 2 layered navigation?
If I have 1000 products and there is 1 where I didnt set the value for attribute, then filter for that attribute is not shown..
Is it default behaviour and how to avoid that?
